# Disable HTTPSession for stateless web services

Tags: java, rest, servlets, restful-architecture, httpsession

I would like to know if **it is possible to disable the `HTTPSession` for an application server handling only web services RESTful**.

I don't know if there are specific application servers or servlet containers designed to handle micro RESTful web services.

I think that disabling completely the session concept will give the following advantages:

- Better performances
- No risk to save data in the session breaking the concept of stateless of a RESTful webservice
- Less classes loaded by the classloader
- No unused information is saved in the session (for example the session id, session state)
- less access to synchronized blocks (I think that at least in the Session the value of lastAccessedTime is updated for every request and this should be done in a synchronized block)

If there is no application server or servlet container that can do that: Is there any other Java *engine* that can handle micro services without creating something similar to an HttpSession?

Comment: I edited the question adding a new request at the end. So it is not the same of the other.

Comment: That only mangles the question by asking a secondary one which is incredibly vague and broad.

Comment: Is not so vague infact Andres answered with a possible engine to do that.

Comment: I'm sure in due time you will see the error in that and start to actually read the things you don't want to read right now - which is the rest of the responses and the possible duplicate I flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable HttpSession on a servlet container, like Tomcat.

Maybe [Play framework](https://www.playframework.com/) would be a good approach for implementing your design.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look of it

Answer (score 1):

You can't completely disable the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

But you can ensure a [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) won't be created in your application. To do it, ensure the following methods are not being invoked (by *yourself* or by the *frameworks you are using*):

- [`HttpServletRequest.getSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession--)
- [`HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession-boolean-) with `true`

---

[Microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) is an architecture design principle. If you want to use [Spring](https://spring.io/), there's a [guide you can follow](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring).

Comment: I called request.getSession(false) and it returns a session also if no other request has been done.

Comment: Then the session has been created elsewhere. Are the rest services embedded in an application that opened the session?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession-boolean-): *If `create` is `false` and the request has no valid `HttpSession`, this method returns `null`*. So, I believe your session is being create elsewhere. Isn't your framework doing it for you?

Comment: I tried again with a simpler example and the session was not created. You @Cassio are right thanks