# How to prevent creating HttpSession in Spring REST Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, httpsession

In our project we have implemented a few REST Services using Spring `@RestController`. The problem is when I test them using a REST Client, in response header there exists `JSESSIONID`, So I believe the server creates an `HTTPSession` for each request, but the services are stateless and they don't need `HTTPSession`.

Is there any way to prevent creating new sessions in this controllers?

---

This is the source of RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customs/customs")
public class CustomsRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomsWebService customsWebService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomsSecurityContextInitializer securityContextInitializer;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/customsPorts", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Collection<CustomsPort> getActiveCustomsPorts() {
        try {
            securityContextInitializer.initSecurityContext();
            return customsWebService.getActiveCustomsPorts();
        } finally {
            securityContextInitializer.clearSecurityContext();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/registerCustomsRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public CustomsDeclarationInfo registerCustomsRequest(@RequestBody CustomsDeclarationRequest requestKey) {
        try {
            securityContextInitializer.initSecurityContext();
            requestKey.validate();
            return customsWebService.registerCustomsRequest(requestKey);
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            return CustomsDeclarationInfo.builder().errorMessage(e.getMessage()).build();
        } finally {
            securityContextInitializer.clearSecurityContext();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817012/how-does-the-httpsession-object-get-bound-to-the-browser

Comment: I think the answer is not correct, an HTTPSession must not be created if you don't ask the server to do it. In normal JSP/Servlet (and many other frameworks) it is default to create an HTTPSession, but in REST Application it is not.

Comment: Please back that up with a source

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673836/disable-httpsession-for-stateless-web-services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable HTTPSession for stateless web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673836/disable-httpsession-for-stateless-web-services)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your implementation of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` by setting the `SessionCreationPolicy` to `STATELESS`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Comment: But I don't have Spring Security in my project.